# Using generic class as type parameter

Tags: java, generics

I would like to use a generic class as a type parameter for another generic class.

At first my class definition was like this:

```
class Foo<T, R extends BaseDto> {}
```

Then my requirements changed and I had to use a wrapper/holder class for my `R` type

My attempt so far: (Gives compile-time error: class or interface expected on `Bar<R>`)

```
class Bar<T extends BaseDto> {
    private T dto;
    public Bar(T dto) {
        this.dto= dto;
    }
    // getters and setters
}
class Foo<T, Bar<R>> {
    private T entity;
    private R dto;
    // getters and setters
}
```

I can not use it as `Foo<T, Object>` because then the clients using this class would not know that they actually need a cast from `Object` to `Bar`.

How would I implement such behaviour?

Comment: Every answerer here seems to have interpreted the question differently... I suggest you post more code, showing how you expect your class to work before and after the requirement change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of changing the class header, replace everywhere in the class where you used `R` with `Bar<R>`.

So the class header stays the same:

```
class Foo<T, R extends CustomClass>
```

But let's say you have a field of type `R`. That needs to be changed to `Bar<R>`:

```
Bar<R> someField;
```

Comment: I've tried this before and it did not work for my case. After reading your answer, tried this again and found out that the error was on my part. The solution is changing the field type from `R` to `Bar<R>`!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you need may be:

```
class Foo<T, R extends CustomClass, S extends Bar<R>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use

```
class Foo<T extends CustomClass, R extends Bar<T>> {}
```

If `Bar` is fixed, i.e., if the user does not need another class extending `Bar`, then you need to get rid of `R` and just use `Bar<T>` inside `Foo`